# Python: "Module Not Found Error" in Virtual environment

Tags: python

I'm a newbie with Python and been trying to install modules using pip unsuccessfully in my small project.

Following advice online, I've created my own virtual environment and imported my first module `cowsay` fine. I can definitely see the module being installed in my project:

[image]

BUT, when attempting to run the file in my terminal, I keep getting a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

```
(env) sr@python-virtual-env >> pip install cowsay
Collecting cowsay
  Using cached cowsay-5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: cowsay
Successfully installed cowsay-5.0

(env) sr@python-virtual-env >> python say.py John
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sr/Sites/python-virtual-env/say.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cowsay
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cowsay'
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious what is `which python pip` output?

Comment: @Vitalizzare the output when I run that command is:

`(env) sr@python-virtual-env  >> which python pip
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
/Users/sr/Sites/python-virtual-env/env/bin/pip`

Comment: It seems the problem is that you have an alias for `python` in your shell login profile which calls a fixed version of python, which means the venv isn't able to select the correct python version.  Don't do that.

Comment: check the selected python interpreter in the right down corner of your vs code. If you click on the selected interpreter it will display all python versions which are installed on your machine. There you must select the python in your venv otherwise it won't recognize the installed modules. Since 'which python pip' points to the correct path i guess it won't be the redirect from 'python' to 'python3' command. I also use that redirect and it's no problem at my machine. Another thing I would rocommend is alway use 'python -m pip install ...' than it will always use the python version of the venv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the output of the command `which python pip` is

```
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3 
/Users/sr/Sites/python-virtual-env/env/bin/pip
```

we can say that you are running the python not from your environment. So it cannot see by default any package installed in this env.

Remove the alias `python` (in bash, the command `unalias python` should be enough for the current session) or print the command with the leading `\` to ignore aliases and look for the python in `$PATH`, like this

```
$ \python say.py John
```

Note `\` at the beginning of this command. But if you have declared `python` as a shell function, this function may be executed (hardly so, but what if some shell behaves this way?). So may be the best way to resolve the problem is to run `env python`, like this:

```
$ env python say.py John
```

### Important update

Having thought somewhat longer about this problem, I can allow myself a categorical answer: `env python ...` is the only way to run python directly from `PATH`.

Here's the model to see why I think so.

Let's say we run `bash` on a linux machine with `PATH='/usr/bin:/bin'` and the only python `/usr/bin/python`:

```
$ bash --version | head -1
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ export PATH='/usr/bin:/bin'
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
```

Making sure we don't have any aliases or functions named `python`:

```
$ type -a python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

Now we define an alias and a function with name `python`:

```
$ alias python='echo Running python as an alias; /usr/bin/python'
$ function python(){ echo Running python as a function; python "$@"; }
```

Let's see what is the answer of `which` and `type` commands now:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
$ type -a python
python is aliased to `echo Running python as an alias; /usr/bin/python'
python is a function
python () 
{ 
    echo Running python as a function;
    echo Running python as an alias;
    /usr/bin/python "$@"
}
python is /usr/bin/python
```

And here we go:

```
$ python -c 'print("Hello world")'
Running python as an alias
Hello world

$ \python -c 'print("Hello world")'
Running python as a function
Running python as an alias
Hello world

$ env python -c 'print("Hello world")'
Hello world
```

As we can see, an alias took precedence over a function in this case, and only `env python` helped to reach the `PATH` directly, which is most desirable when running python from a local environment.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. It was the alias indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Finding bugs in a venv is quite a pain. There can be many causes that lead to finding the cause is like looking for a needle in a haystack. Recently I had to set up my venv again today because it was destroyed by an update. Here are step-by-step instructions on how to get your problem solved quickly.

1. Go to the root of your project and activate the venv (if it is not already activated) and run the command `python -m pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This creates a document listing all of your installed packages. You need this to be able to install them all again later without any problems.
2. Close VS Code and open a command line. Delete the venv you installed.
3. Navigate to the root directory of your project in the command line and execute the following command `python -m venv ./venv`
   This creates a venv in the root directory of your project.
4. Open the project in VS Code. VS Code usually detects that a new venv has been created and asks you if you want to use it. [image]Answer the question with "yes".
5. Check in the bottom right corner of VS Code if the correct python interpreter (the one in your venv) is selected. It will look like that:
   [image]
   If this is not the case, select the correct interpreter. You can find how to do that [here](https://www.alphr.com/vs-code-change-python-interpreter/).
6. Open a terminal in VS Code and make sure venv is enabled.
7. Run the following command `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` This will install all packages from the document "requirements.txt"

Now everything should work properly.

Comment: This is the easiest way to ensure everything is installed correctly. The whole thing is done in two minutes and saves you hours of troubleshooting. If it still doesn't work, it's very likely that it's not because of the venv.